# Python-API, custom interface: How do I recreate mesh/vertex data settings from the 3D View sidebar (for example to manipulate vertex group weights)?

Tags: python, mesh, edit-mode, vertex-weights, panel

I want to use some mesh settings from the 3D view sidebar and put them in a different place for a custom interface. I have already filled the sidebar with different extra buttons and object settings from the properties window which is no problem, because for these its mostly rightclicking on the desired button etc to "Edit Source" and you can see in the script how it was done in Blender or to copy it in my own script.
Unfortunately everyone of those mesh data settings that are only accessable in edit mode (image below) give the error "Active button is not from a script, cannot edit source":

[image: 3D View Sidebar - Edit Mode Settings]

I wonder if this is something that is doable with Blenders python API? I have tried to go into bmesh with it but found it hard to understand. I always end with buggy meshes and Blender crashes and it seems like I need more than a hint or snippet of code to get started.

To begin with I am most interested in getting the vertex group weights of the active vertex listed and have them changable in edit mode (0 to 1.0). No sorting or additional stuff.

I would like to use one of Blenders python templates (UI Panel Simple) as starting point. There was no real progress to speak of with the issue on my side over the years so I only hope someone can fill this with an example code that is working in order to get me an understanding of it (sry!):

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the 3D View sidebar"""
    bl_label = "Another Vertex Weights Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Item"


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="What to do?", icon='QUESTION')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
   
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```